# Word between rare and common

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm searching for an adjective that is between rare and common - e.g. something that is everyday, or ordinary, or not remarkable.

Can anyone help suggest some words I might try?

Thank you,

Comment: Example sentence?

Comment: Wouldn't "ordinary" or "everyday" be much like common? They're words I find in dictionaries and a thesaurus together.

Comment: That's about half the dictionary.

Comment: I agree with Zebrafish. The post is misleading. "everyday, or ordinary" is not between rare and common it is just common.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **common** *is* something everyday or ordinary.

However, if you want a word that's between *rare* and *common* on a frequency scale, I suggest [**occasional**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasional):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **3** : encountered, occurring, appearing, or taken at irregular or infrequent intervals
> // *occasional* visitors
> // an *occasional* vacation
> // found *occasional* errors
> // *occasional* episodes of chest pain

In addition to the synonyms *irregular* and *infrequent* shown in the definition, there is also *intermittent*.

Comment: In this definition it's described as "infrequent", which I consider to be somewhere in between "common" and "rare". Sure, I wouldn't place it right in the middle of the spectrum, but this is the best answer so far. Also, some people may use "occasionally" to mean up to 30, 40 or 50% frequency(???). So I think it's a good word.

Comment: Thank you! I agree - I think occasional captures what I am looking for. It's not perfect, but perhaps there isn't a perfect word in this case :) Appreciate all the other input from everyone, too :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is **mundane**:

From Merriam Webster:

> 2 : characterized by the practical, transitory, and ordinary : COMMONPLACE
>
> // the mundane concerns of day-to-day life

Comment: I think "mundane" is very much like "common". Look, it says there in your definition, well kind of, "commonplace".

Answer (score 0):

How about "uncommon"? Typically the word used in gaming circles.

Comment: This would benefit from more information including a citation.  It has been flagged by the system as low quality.  Please see the [help].

Answer (score 0):

> I'm searching for an adjective that is between rare and common - e.g. something that is everyday, or ordinary, or not remarkable.

That I think *is* a bit contradictory because *everyday*, *ordinary*, or *unremarkable* are all synonymous with *common* rather than "between rare and common."

That said, how about "sporadic"?
[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sporadic) defines it as follows:

> : occurring occasionally, singly, or in irregular or random instances 
> *sporadic* protests
> a *sporadic* disease

Answer (score -1):

Here is an answer from an engineer’s point of view:

The International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) has a defined standard IEC 61508, describing a model for specific occurrence probabilities for different likelihood categories, per year:

- Frequent   (>10^-3)
- Probable   (10^-3 to 10^-4)
- Occasional (10^-4 to 10^-5)
- Remote     (10^-5 to 10^-6)
- Improbable (10^-6 to 10^-7)
- Incredible (<10^-7)

I propose you have a look at this URL

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61508#Hazard_and_risk_analysis